# Update the ID(auto increment column) of a row

Tags: mysql

I am having one table in which ID column is 'Auto Increment' set.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
        ID   int(11) unsigned int not null auto_increment,
        Name  varchar(20)
        )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I have one row in table whose ID filed is 100. But I want to move this row to the next auto incremental value. Let's say if the last row entered in the table is 1005 so row of `ID=100` will move to 1006.

Simple way to solve this problem is

Select -> Insert -> Delete

But I want to know if I can do something like below:

```
UPDATE table SET ID=last_insert_id()+1 where ID=100
```

Comment: Can you use any server side programming language like PHP?

Comment: Why don't you want to solve it the 'simple' way?

Comment: There are some comments in here about issues you may have if you do an update on an auto-increment column depending on table type : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: If you care about the value of an auto_incrementing ID then it should not be an auto_incremeting id.

Comment: Yes i can use PHP.
Solving in simple way will be three DB read/write command.
I am using first 100 row for some special purpose and once the purpose finish i want to move those row to normal.